# What if I don't want to complete my notice period, Due to Negative workplace behavior?

Tags: software-industry, company-culture, india, notice-period, company-policy

My company **cutting my salary 30%** due to covid work from home [this is not just for me it's for all employees working in the company. They said the productivity of employees is decreased. They giving tasks with the deadline. We are working and we are getting paid 30% less salary just because we are working from home]. Also, they said they created a **PF account** and **didn't provide any information about it** so we are losing that amount from our salary and have no idea where it is going. **Didn't get any salary increment in the last 1 year and 7 months**. These all things are not just happening to me, everyone at our office suffering this.
 As the first one standing against them they are now treating me like a terrorist.
So I submitted my resignation. As a professional courtesy,**I completed my 1 month notice period**. now they asked me to serve **3 month notice period** to give me my relieving letter and experience certificate.

Where can I complain against it? or how can I overcome this issue.. I am a programmer with 5 years of experience in the same company. I have a job offer where I have to join within a month.

This boss is creating a toxic environment and I don't even want to stay there for another day.

Comment: Location tag please. India right?

Comment: @NathanCooper yes, India

Comment: How much notice did they give you for cutting your salary by 30%? Can you prove you gave your notice last month? Can you talk to your new employer and ask for their advice?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk this 30% cutting is there for the last 1 year and 7 months.  I can prove this 1 one month because I submitted my resignation via mail. The new employer is ok with it but I will lose my 5-year experience, that's what I am worried about..

Comment: @SilverSurfer, What they're doing is blackmail and extortion. Do not succumb to it. If you accept the three additional months, they'll just do the same thing over again in three months. It's never going to end! I don't know the law in India, but if you've convinced one employer that you were indeed employed during those 5 years, you should be able to convince another one in the future as well. Just keep your pay stubs, bank account records, copy of emails, pictures, awards, at your home. Stay in contact with your former colleagues (the other victims). And do not succumb to this coercion.

Comment: If you rally your colleagues and get everyone to agree to provide references for each other, then that's one way to beat this extortion scheme.

Comment: Make the 30% back by asking the company to pay for your electricity use, broadband use and anything else your using at home to do the job.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I decided to get out from the company as soon as possible.. hoping for the best.